# resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, persistence

I am learning to use Hibernate in my Java web app. I have the following sessionFactory started with a configuration for the location of my hibernate.cfg.xml file, but it still complains: `resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found`

**The "resources" folder is a subdirectory of my "src" folder in the java project.**

```
public class HibernateUtil
{
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Book book1 = new Book("John Wright", "Unknown Title");
        session.save(book1);
        tx.commit();

        System.out.println("Book committed: book title: " + book1.getTitle() + ", author is: " + book1.getAuthor());
        sessionFactory.close();
    }


}
```

The hibernate dependency I'm using in my pom.xml is as follows, but **intelliJ warns that the buildSessionFactory() method is deprecated** by highlight a "Strikethrough"

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am posting the error message from my i at the very bottom as well. What is going wrong? thanks

```
10:43:12.737 [main] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
10:43:12.746 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
10:43:12.747 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:43:12.749 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: resources/hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:2093)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2074)
    at persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    ... 3 more
10:43:12.763 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000043: Configuring from resource: resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
10:43:12.763 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000040: Configuration resource: resources/hibernate.cfg.xml

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Just to make sure, the hibernate.cfg.xml is in src/main/resources? Maven is very particular with its project structure...

Comment: no, it's src/resources, but even if I move resources to src/main, same error persists

Comment: Did you setup Maven to include that in the final build then? Generally Maven has src/main/java for all of your java files and src/main/resources for all of your other files. With that structure Maven automatically knows where everything is and that they all need to be included. Additionally, if you put it in src/main/resources, you would not specify it as .configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml") but instead as .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml") unless you make folders under the resources folder.

Comment: still doesn't work with .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"), thanks

Comment: Even after moving the file to src/main/resources?

Comment: yes, I moved the files under resources to the path src/main/resources

Answer (score 1):

Your hibernate config file cannot be found because it is not in the root of the classpath when the webapp is started...

When you are using Maven, putting the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the src/main/resources folder should cause it to automatically get copied to WEB-INF/classes in the WAR file. Open your WAR file and see where the hibernate.cfg.xml is being placed.

If the hibernate.cfg.xml file is NOT in your WAR file ... double check the maven-war-plugin settings in your POM.

Regarding the deprecation warning, as per the [4.3 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/), buildSessionFactory() is deprecated and you should be using buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry) instead.

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for the replies.

Finally, I've figured it out. Below is my configuration in my HibernateUtil class. Because I'm using Hibernate 4.3.5, I've replaced the deprecated methods with the latest ones. Also I moved my hibernate.cfg.xml to `src/main/java/resources`.

```
static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial sessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```